# How to transfer file to and from Telegram using POCO (I don't want to use any middleware)

Tags: c#, httpclient, file-transfer, telegram-bot

I'm currently working on a Telegram bot, recently i almost finished it's sensitive parts, and now i want to activate the webhook, but the webhook require me to send certificate file to the telegram before it get activated, also later i may want to send a file for our client, or receive their reply as a file (since we want to activate our website features to them through telegram).

Here is a reference to telegram bot APIs:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputfile

I, myself, done all my api call through HttpClient class, and i wish to continue it as it is.
here is my failed method:

```
    public static Exception SetWebhook(SetWebhook webhook)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var hc = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpContent requestContent = new ObjectContent(typeof(SetWebhook), webhook,
                    new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
                    {
                        SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                        {
                            ContractResolver = new CustomPropertyNamesContractResolver
                            {
                                Case = IdentifierCase.UnderscoreSeparator
                            },
                            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                        },
                        SupportedEncodings = {Encoding.UTF8}
                    }, "multipart/form-data");

                var responseMessage =
                    hc.PostAsync("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + AppSetting.Token + "/setWebhook",
                        requestContent).Result;

                if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    return new Exception("Status Code: " + responseMessage.StatusCode + "\n\nRequest" + responseMessage.RequestMessage.ToString() + "\n\nResponse" + responseMessage.ToString() );
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex;
        }
    }
```

And here are my models:
Since telegram didn't defined the Certificate exact type, i take a look at this: https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot to generate it.

```
public class SetWebhook
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Optional<br/>
    /// If empty remove webhook
    /// </summary>
    public string Url { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Optional<br/>
    /// Upload your public key certificate so that the root certificate in use can be checked. See our self-signed guide for details.
    /// </summary>
    public InputFile Certificate { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Represents information for a file to be sent
/// </summary>
public class InputFile
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required <b/>
    /// Gets or sets the filename.
    /// </summary>
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Required <b/>
    /// Gets or sets the content.
    /// </summary>
    public Stream Content { get; set; }

    public InputFile()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="InputFile"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">The <see cref="Filename"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="content">The <see cref="Content"/>.</param>
    public InputFile(string filename, Stream content)
    {
        Filename = filename;
        Content = content;
    }
}
```

and here is the way i call it:

```
public ActionResult SetWebhook()
    {
        var result = true;
        var text = "-";

        try
        {
            WebHook.SetWebhook("http://ravis.ir:444/Data/Message", Server.MapPath("~/Files/ravis.ir-PEM.cer"));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            result = false;
            text = ex.Message;
        }

        return View(new WebhookResult
        {
            Result = result,
            Text = text
        });
    }
```

This last way, errors:

`((ex.InnerException).InnerException).Message` ->
*Timeouts are not supported on this stream.*

`(ex.InnerException).Message` ->
*Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'System.IO.FileStream'.*

`ex.Message` ->
*One or more errors occurred.*

So how should i send file? how should i receive them? what kind of entity should i define to be more accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get this working you should construct `MultipartFormDataContent` with `StreamContent` inside (not an `ObjectContent`):

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
using (var form = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    var content = new StreamContent(setWebhook.Certificate.Content);
    form.Add(content, "certificate", setWebhook.Certificate.Filename);
    form.Add(new StringContent(setWebhook.Url, Encoding.UTF8), "url");

    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, form);
}
```

---

As for receiving files - first you should get "file info" containing `file_path` and then it can be downloaded:

```
var fileId = "fileId";

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/getFile", new { file_id = fileId });
    responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var fileInfoResponse = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<TelegramResponse<FileInfo>>();

    var fileUri = new Uri("https://api.telegram.org/file/bot" + token + "/" + fileInfoResponse.result.file_path);
    var fileStreamResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(fileUri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    //and here's downloaded file
    var stream = await fileStreamResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
}
```

Here `TelegramResponse` and `FileInfo` will look something like this (* not a C# convention, but you can fix this if you want):

```
class TelegramResponse<T>
{
    public bool ok { get; set; }
    public T result { get; set; }
}
class FileInfo
{
    public string file_path { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. what about receiving files? as i mention i need both send and receive.

Comment: for now i didn't need to transfer file, in or out, but soon i gonna need, for now i only needed to transfer it for webhooks, which didn't worked. (your code, i still didn't test it, had stuff to do in this morning, will try it now)

Comment: There something seem not right... I have `SetWebhook` class, you see, and it contain two data, a file data, and a URL, the url is not the address i want to post to, but the URL which after calling this method, the calling server will use to contact mine. but you only send a single file without this data...

Comment: how does this work? a multipart can add any kind of content to itself? like i add a steamcontent and a objectcontent and ... ?

Comment: unfortunately still it has error, but fortunately i could solve the rest, and it was telegram restriction which itself provided message for. so as this were my main part of question, you earn. but can you help me further more? i get no message from telegram, is my web app right? `public void Message(Update update){} inside of DataController. and here is my passed URL: https://deadmann.tk:8443/Data/Message

Comment: Did you tried to call this url by yourself to check if it is valid?

Comment: at first the firewall blocked, also i forgot that it were a api link, not mvc link, so it's like: [https://deadmann.tk:8443/api/Data/Message](https://deadmann.tk:8443/api/Data/Message), but still doesn't work, i mean telegram doesn't send any request to my server... i debugging the IIS, so it should break

Comment: Verify that when you sending post request **manually** (by yourself) to this url with following [data](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update) you actually get it - add logs or something

Comment: i send UpdateId using Advance Rest Client application, and it trapped the request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116287/discussion-between-deadmann-and-aleksey-l).